# First UIView not autosizing to fit iPhone 5 or iPad

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uiview, iphone-5

I  have a simple app with multiple UIViews. I've recently begun work to create a universal app out of it get the auto-sizing and rotation of views working with the iPhone 5 and iPad.

On my very first view, the view comes up as the standard 3.5" display with a white bar beneath it on the iPhone 5 (and beside it on the iPad). There is also a toolbar attached to the bottom of the view and it appears at the place where it would be on a 3.5" display. The strange thing is, when I go to another view and then return to the root view, the view is sized correctly.

I've checked my autosizing for the view - all outside and inside anchors are activated. My view mode is set to "scale to fit," and in comparison to other views, settings are the same. And the strange thing is it comes up right the second time the view is displayed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Stranger things afoot... 

The app DOES autoresize on iPad / iOS6.1 simulator.

Does NOT autoresize on iPhone 5 / iOS6.1 simulator.
Does NOT autoresize on iPad / iOS5.1 simulator.

Comment: The whole constraint-based auto resizing system was introduced in iOS 6, I think, so it's not so strange that it's not working in iOS 5.

Comment: I get that, but what I didn't get was why IPHONE 5 /iOS6 would NOT resize but IPAD / iOS6 WOULD... I don't think I was getting consistent results though, so it may have just been any device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. It was in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of the application.

I changed:

```
 UIView *rootView = self.rootViewController.view;
 CGRect rootViewFrame = rootView.frame;
 rootViewFrame.origin.y +=[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
```

to

```
 UIView *rootView = self.rootViewController.view;
 CGRect rootViewFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
```

The app was picking up the hard coded size of the view from the XIB when the view first loaded; now I just fit it within the application frame.